# Android is behaving unexpectedly to a null value

Tags: android, logcat

I have an object. This object has a string property which is null (it looks null in the database, I get it as a JSON object and parse it and then create the object.)

When I try to do something like below when it is null, it doesn't do it, it behaves like it is not null :

```
if(object.Type == null)
//do this
else
//do that
```

When I try to print its value in Logcat like below, that line just doesn't work, no error or something like that, it just skips that line:

```
Log.d("value of the type", object.type);
```

I'm pretty confused and I can't find any mistake with the code. I'd accept any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Because that object is null, then how will you get it's type.

Comment: Cant believe a Log.d line is not showing on logcat, as i remember it will throw exception if you try to print a null string, have you tried with a breakpoint?

Comment: if is checking for `Type`. Log is printing `type`. It would be really helpful if you would post the real code with a clear explanation of what is the expected behaviour

Comment: there is no such thing in java, .type must be the string property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This object has a string property which is null**

try this code :

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty((object.Type)){
//do this
}else{
//do that
}
```